# Mobile device doesn't use cookie

Tags: ajax, django, mobile, django-rest-framework

For some reason the mobile authentication detection stoped working. When I access a location containing a form on my page, the form should call (via ajax) for additional information to fill the fields, the server returns depending on user authentification. It worked well for nine months, but stoped working for mobile devices, however it still works for desktop browser access. Mobile and desktop use exactly the same access route, arguments, urls, view function ... everything. The one difference that I noted (after some 8 hours on this issue) when I looked up the request.META, is that desktop sends cookie information, mobile doesn't. However cookies are enabled on mobile and desktop browser. I tested this with Chrome mobile and (a freshly installed) Firefox on mobile, the result is exactly the same.

How is this possible? Why does the form when initializing on desktop send the cookie info and when initializing on mobile don't send it?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44645811/django-rest-framework-rest-auth-not-authenticating-user-on-mobile-chrome) is a previous version of this question (written before I noticed the cookie difference and thought it was an api issue) containing technical details that I don't consider to be relevant for the particular question of how does the same functionality behave some differently on mobile and desktop.

EDIT: I really don't know what code to show, but probably the ajax request could be relevant. I am really lost here. This is the react-js service I use to load form initials, it's the one that arrives without cookie information when send form mobile device, and with cookie if send from desktop device, to the server. I am not aware to have added anything or changed this in anyway in the past nine months, it always worked only like this:

```
loadFormInitials = (typ,genderRelevant,auth) => {

    $.ajax({
      url: UserConstants.BASE_URL+'elements/?item=setup&auth='+auth,
      method: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: (result) => {
        var data = JSON.parse(result.initial_data);
        FormActions.loadFormInitialsAction(data,typ,genderRelevant);

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile companies sometime alter HTTP requests with their heavy caching.
You'd probably want to try again with HTTPS requests, not sure it'll fix though.

Comment: But there must be a way to use a cookie on a mobile browser, right? It can not go lost just so ..

Comment: ooooooooooooooooooooooooooh GOD!!!!!!!!!!!1111!2!!! ... yes that's the whole issue, the dev server points to http by default and it doesn't pass .. by adding "s" in the url it works all fine. I spend the whole f************* day on this, 10 hrs ... my god .. thanks for pointing my in the right direction.